# using multiprocessing to handle socket

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a server with main process acepting socket connections and put them in Queue stack and another process monitoring this stack and applying it to pool processes handling connections. All works fine except for one thing:

- last connection allways at stuck until another connection appears, it's look like last connection can't be closed, but why?

```python
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Pool, Manager
import datetime
import socket

def get_date():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server_address = host, port
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


    def run(self):
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server_socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.server_socket.listen(1)

        print('listen at: %s:%s' % self.server_address)

        q = Manager().Queue()
        Process(target=self.handle_request, args=(q,)).start()

        while True:
            client_socket, adress = self.server_socket.accept()
            print('\n[%s] request from: %s:%s' % (get_date(), *adress))
            q.put(client_socket)
            client_socket.close()
            del client_socket  # client_socket.close() not working


    def help(self, client_socket):
        data = client_socket.recv(512)
        client_socket.send(data)
        client_socket.close()
        print(data[:50])

    def handle_request(self, q):
        with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            while True:
                pool.apply_async(self.help, (q.get(),))


Server('localhost', 8000).run()
```

Comment: This does not look like a good use case for the use of the `del` statement. Even if you can't get the socket closing thing straightened out, you really shouldn't `del` anything.

Comment: you should start subprocess before init parent listen socket, otherwise, it will be shared to all child processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`close` doesn't realy close connection unless no other process holding a reference, but `shutdown` will affect all processes. you could call `client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` before `client_socket.close()`.

---

Update:

the reason `close` doesn't fully close connection is there is a process started by `Manager()` is holding a reference. Use `Queue` instead would make `close` works as you expected.

Comment: Adding a link to the [relevant section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) would be helpful.